# MySQL - How to select only two columns from a row in one table

Tags: php, mysql, select

I've looked everywhere for this answer and haven't found a single link that has helped me out for this which is surprising! So my problem is the following...

I have a table in my database called users. In that table I have two columns out of a about 5 or 6 other ones. I need to select ONLY userid and username from each row in the users table.

Here is my current query which is only pulling in the username. I don't want to pull in everything (ie using *) because I don't think that would be secure and wise considering things like emails and passwords aren't necessary in this case.

My current query string...

```
$users = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT username FROM users") or die($posts . "<br/>" . mysqli_error($sql));
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html - it's SQL 101.

Comment: Irrelevant when it's 3am ;) Oops!

Comment: Try 4-5 pots of coffee and up for 30 hours <= *don't do this*; I've been there, never going back; *least I hope not*. Sleep is the most important thing when writing code. Get some sleep and code with a fresh head, you'll thank me for it ;)

Comment: I know, I know. It's just I'm new-ish to PHP and MySQL and I'm learning so much so fast I don't want to have a break ha. Thanks for helping though, and everyone else. Making some great progress! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column identifiers are just a comma separated list after your SELECT statement and before the FROM clause

```
$users = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT userid, username FROM users") or die($posts . "<br/>" . mysqli_error($sql));
```

Comment: I think there might be a catch. Probably wants the whole 9yds., given posted code. ;)

Comment: I really want to kick myself haha. That is literally all I needed. I think it might have to do with me trying to write a web app at 3am. Thank you so much! **Edit** I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: "Give a man fish, he'll eat for a day. Teach him how to fish, and he'll sit in a boat and drink beer all day."

Comment: @spencer7593 I'm gonna have to write that one down. Now where'd that can 'o worms go?

Comment: Worms, it's what's for dinner (after the beer's gone and the cooler's empty)